# Input Box centralizado na <td>

Tags: php, html, laravel

Gostaria de saber como posso centralizar os `inputs` no código a seguir.

```
@foreach ($riscos as $risco)
          <tr>
          <th class="row-header">{{ $risco->risk}}</th>
          @for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++)
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="" style="width: 30px;" text-align="center">
              </div>
            </form>
          </td>
          @endfor
        @endforeach
```

Está ficando assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LIQd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tem uma opção bem simples, primeiro NUNCA mudo o `display` de nenhum elemento relacionada a `table`, então jamais mudo por exemplo uma `td` ou `th` para `display:flex` por exemplo.

Dito isso aproveite essa `div` que tem o `input` dentro e trabalhe com ele, eu usei `display:grid` nela junto de um `place-items: center` e resolveu.

```css
td,
th {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.form-group {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="row-header">{{ $risco->risk}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="" style="width: 30px;" text-align="center">
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```